# Grid data not visible on front-end

Tags: css, extjs, frontend, extreact

I am currently working on an existing Ext React project which might have existing styles and CSS. I created a new Grid component and passed hard-coded data. It is not visible on the front-end although when I inspect the element I can see that data in the code. Being new to Ext JS and Ext React stack, I am unable to debug this.

From what I have observed, it is being rendered on the front end as I can inspect it, but it is not visible. I tried setting color, changing margins and padding, and other such CSS changes. What are some other things I should look out for?

Comment: Please share a sample code of the issue if possible!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a fixed height and width?